# Extract specific triples from turtle file using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I am in a learning phase of SPARQL. I am using rdflib to extract some triples from a graph. I have loaded the triple file and stored it is a graph object. The turtle file looks like below.

```
https://ontology/meddra_10047786 http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref umls:C0520587
https://ontology/meddra_10047786 http://formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym buschke-lã¶wenstein tumor
https://ontology/efo_12343 http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref umls:C454654
https://ontology/meddra_10047786 http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref mesh:D487584
```

I would like to extract the triples with medra as a subject and predicate should have a relation relation hasDbXref and value should have mesh and in the end would like to save it in a dataframe. The expected output is:

```
https://ontology/meddra_10047786 http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref mesh:D487584
```

I am using following lines of code but it is very slow.

```
for s, p, o in g:
    if "meddra" in s and p = "http://formats/oboInOwl#hasExactSynonym":
        print (s, p, o)
    else:
        pass
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please use containment checks as documented [here](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_graphs.html) or write a SPARQL query. And indeed, you should use the URI of medra such that an index can be used instead of iterating all triples to check if the subject URI contains the string

Answer (score 0):

> extract the triples with medra as a subject

You do not have "medra" as any subject but rather the string "medra" within subject IRIs. This means you can't query direct for "medra" but only look up subjects like `<https://ontology/meddra_10047786>` that contain "medra". So you are converting between RDFLib objects and simple strings etc. This is error prone and will be slow if you have lots of triples.

You should tag things with "medra" in some way that you can then use in queries, for example:

Case 1:

```
<https://ontology/meddra_10047786>
    dcat:keyword "medra" ;
.
```

or

Case 2:

```
<https://ontology/meddra_10047786>
    dcterms:type <http://example.com/medra> ;
.
```

Now you can filter on that like this, for Case 1:

```py
for s, o in g.subject_objects(predicate=DCAT.keyword):
    if str(o) == "medra":
        for o2 in g.objects(subject=s, predicate=URIRef("http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref")):
           print(s, o2)  # prints subjects & objects
```

For Case 2:

```py
for s in g.subjects(predicate=DCTERMS.type, object=URIRef("http://example.com/medra"):
    for g.objects(subject=s, predicate=predicate=URIRef("http://formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref")):
        print(s, o2)  # prints subjects & objects
```